# Which Pokemon can have Mega Evolution states?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

From what I've seen so far, it's largely limited to old starters and old legendaries.

Which Pokemon in Pokemon X & Y can have Mega Evolution states?    Is it strictly limited to older generations of Pokemon, or is there a certain set of Pokemon that share this feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Pokemon that have mega evolutions at the moment are somewhat arbitrary, in my opinion.  Notably the only starters on the list are the Kanto starters (one of which has TWO versions) and Blaizken, and there are no new sixth generation Pokemon with a mega evolution! [According to Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/megaevolutions.shtml) this is the current list (and this is believed to be final at this point, as there are no other known mega stones).

- [Venusaur](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Venusaur)
- [Charizard](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Charizard) (two formes, X and Y)
- [Blastoise](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Blastoise)
- [Alakazam](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Alakazam)
- [Gengar](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gengar)
- [Kangaskhan](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kangaskhan)
- [Pinsir](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pinsir)
- [Gyarados](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gyarados)
- [Aerodactyl](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aerodactyl)
- [Mewtwo](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mewtwo) (two formes, X and Y)
- [Ampharos](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ampharos)
- [Scizor](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Scizor)
- [Heracross](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Heracross)
- [Houndoom](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Houndoom)
- [Tyranitar](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tyranitar)
- [Blaziken](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Blaziken)
- [Gardevoir](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gardevoir)
- [Mawile](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mawile)
- [Aggron](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aggron)
- [Medicham](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Medicham)
- [Manectric](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Manectric)
- [Banette](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Banette)
- [Absol](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Absol)
- [Garchomp](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Garchomp)
- [Lucario](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lucario)
- [Abomasnow](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Abomasnow)

Note that most mega evolutions have different abilities, and a few even change their typing!

Comment: Whoa, this was fast.  Thanks a bunch! If possible, could you keep this updated if anything changes?

Comment: I happened to be looking into this earlier - I thought this list sounded so ridiculous that there was no way it was correct, but it sounds like there's no question at this point. It may be technically feasible on a 3DS game to patch new ones in later, but data mining right now seems to indicate this is all that's in the game right now. :/  Absolutely will update if that changes though.

Comment: No sixth-gens though...that's really dissapointing

Comment: New leaks seem to indicate there may be a few more in the game code that aren't available...but until it's official I won't be adding it here.

Comment: Thats probably not the whole list. There could be plenty more event mega stones, like BLaziken. I certainly find it odd that blaziken can leave Swampert and Sceptilein more obscurity than allready.

Comment: The ones leaked (currently only two more) are NOT starters.  Odds are if there were any more in there they'd have found them by now.

Comment: @earthmeLon - The official Nintendo spelling is "formes", so I've reverted your edit.  (Yes, it's stupid, but that's how they spell it.)

Comment: That commit you reverted had a lot of other work involved.  Maybe next time instead of reverting, edit the edit to correct it? <3

Comment: @earthmeLon - Yikes, sorry, I didn't actually notice that you'd added links, the formatting on the edit view page made it nonobvious...can't really tell unless you mouse over them.  (I really think adding the links is a pointless edit, not everything needs a hyperlink especially something as patently obvious as this...but if I had noticed that you'd done it in the first place I would have left it, sorry!)

Answer (score 4):

Whilst the list above is still true for Pokemon X & Y - Pokemon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire have introduced new Mega Evolutions:

- [Beedrill](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Beedrill)
- [Pidgeot](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pidgeot)
- [Slowbro](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Slowbro)
- [Steelix](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Steelix)
- [Sceptile](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sceptile)
- [Swampert](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Swampert)
- [Sableye](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sableye)
- [Sharpedo](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sharpedo)
- [Camerupt](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Camerupt)
- [Altaria](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Altaria)
- [Glalie](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Glalie)
- [Salamence](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Salamence)
- [Metagross](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Metagross)
- [Latias](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Latias)
- [Latios](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Latios)
- [Rayquaza](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rayquaza)
- [Lopunny](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lopunny)
- [Gallade](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gallade)
- [Audino](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Audino)
- [Diancie](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Diancie)

As well as the two 'Primal Reversion' Evolutions

- [Kyogre](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kyogre)
- [Groudon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Groudon)